# Flutter: Replace particular string after '.jpg'

Tags: flutter, dart

I have strings of jpg name

```
a = '123a.jpg'
b = '456asa.jpg'
c = '789pa.jpg'
```

Is there a way to replace the final `a` before `.jpg` with `b`?

```
new_a = '123b.jpg'
new_b = '456asb.jpg'
new_c = '789pb.jpg'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a small work arround:

```
a = a.split('').reversed.join().replaceFirst('a', 'b').split('').reversed.join();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
String newa = a.replace("a.", "b.");
```

Edit. You can also do

```dart
newa = a.replaceAll("a$","b");
```

Here $ means last index

Comment: This won't work if the final a was not directly before the dot.

Comment: You added all a.jpg so added that answer. Edited my answer with another solution